# How to extract the value of a given key based on the value of another key, from a list of nested (not-always-existing) dictionaries [Python]

Tags: python, dictionary, nested-loops

I have a **list** of dictionaries called `api_data`, where each dictionary has this structure:

```
{

'location': 
    {
    'indoor': 0, 
    'exact_location': 0, 
    'latitude': '45.502', 
    'altitude': '133.9', 
    'id': 12780, 
    'country': 'IT', 
    'longitude': '9.146'
    },

'sampling_rate': None, 
'id': 91976363, 
'sensordatavalues': 
    [   
        {
        'value_type': 'P1', 
        'value': '8.85', 
        'id': 197572463
        }, 


        {
        'value_type': 'P2', 
        'value': '3.95', 
        'id': 197572466
        }

        {
        'value_type': 'temperature', 
        'value': '20.80', 
        'id': 197572625
        }, 

        {
        'value_type': 'humidity', 
        'value': '97.70', 
        'id': 197572626
        }
    ], 

'sensor': 
    {
    'id': 24645, 
    'sensor_type': 
        {
        'name': 'DHT22', 
        'id': 9, 
        'manufacturer': 
        'various'
        }, 

    'pin': '7'
    }, 

'timestamp': '2020-04-18 18:37:50'

},
```

This structure is not complete for each dictionary, meaning that sometimes a dictionary, a list element or a key is missing.

I want to extract the value of a key when the key value of the same dictionary is equal to a certain value.
For example, for dictionary `sensordatavalues`, I want the value of the key `'value'` when `'value_type'` is equal to `'P1'`.

I have developed this code working with for and if cycles, but I bet it is heavily inefficient. 
How can I do it in a quicker and more efficient way?

Please note that `sensordatavalues` always exists

```
for sensor in api_data:

    sensordatavalues = sensor['sensordatavalues']
    # L_sdv = len(sensordatavalues)

    for physical_quantity_recorded in sensordatavalues:

        if physical_quantity_recorded['value_type'] == 'P1':

            PM10_value = physical_quantity_recorded['value']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you are confident that the value 'P1' is unique to the key you are searching, you can use the 'in' operator with dict.values()
2. Should be ok to omit this assignment: `sensordatavalues = sensor['sensordatavalues']`

```
for sensor in api_data:

    for physical_quantity_recorded in sensor['sensordatavalues']:

        if 'P1' in physical_quantity_recorded.values():

            PM10_value = physical_quantity_recorded['value']
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need one `for` loop:

```
for x in api_data["sensordatavalues"]:
    if x["value_type"] == "P1":
        print(x["value"])
```

Output:

```
8.85
```

Comment: It points out an error at the first line:
TypeError - list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Answer (score 1):

Use `dictionary.get()` method if the key not exist it will return default value

```
for physical_quantity_recorded in api_data['sensordatavalues']:
    if physical_quantity_recorded.get('value_type', 'default_value') == 'P1':
        PM10_value = physical_quantity_recorded.get('value', 'default_value')
```

Comment: It points out an error at the first line: TypeError - list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: for me it's working can you tell me which input with are you testing

Comment: Just to be clear, api_data is a list containing many dictionaries, and the above data example is just 1 element of api_data. Correct?

Comment: yeah, just taking the `sensordatavalues` from `api_data`

Comment: @befunkt is correct. The data comes from this URL https://data.sensor.community/airrohr/v1/filter/area=45.463704,9.187689,8 (its content varies time by time). But let's suppose that the input api_data is this one in this text file: https://github.com/tommasosansone91/aqi_luftdaten/blob/master/api_data_example.txt

Comment: @Tms91 it's working with the data in the txt file what problem are you getting?

Comment: @komatiraju032 What data type do you store the data that you can reference element ['sensordatavalues']? Tms91 is parsing a list object, so ['sensordatavalues'] would not work without converting the data appropriately.

Comment: Sorry, I think the discrepancy is clear here. @komatiraju032, the above example data is a single data set. api_data is a list containing several thousand data sets. The first loop that OP coded was to iterate through the individual data sets, whereas your example code only iterates through a single data set.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear before, api_data is a list containing several dozens of dictionaries like the one I showed in the question (basically a big dictionary of dictionaries).

Answer (score 1):

this is an alternative: [jmespath](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.py) - allows you to search and filter a nested dict/json :

summary of jmespath ... to access a key, use the `.` notation, if ur values are in a list, u access it via the `[]` notation

NB: dict is wrapped in a *data* variable

````
import jmespath
#sensordatavalues is a key, so we can access it directly
#the values of sensordatavalues are wrapped in a list
#to access it we pass the bracket(```[]```)
#we are interested in the dict where value_type is P1
#in jmespath, we identify that using the ? mark to precede the filter object
#pass the filter
#and finally access the key we are interested in ... value

expression = jmespath.compile('sensordatavalues[?value_type==`P1`].value')
expression.search(data)
['8.85']
````